# Call class instance from another class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Is there anything wrong with this kind of structure?  Is there a more pythonic way to do something like this?

The backend class has a variety of data manipulation methods.  Frontend main method is a state machine that deals with Kivy UI (button deactivation logic, control screens, etc)

```
class Backend:
    def one(self):
        pass

class Frontend:
    def main(self):
        B.one()

B = Backend()
F = Frontend()
F.main()
```

Comment: Have you considered  injecting the backend instance into the front end instance?

Comment: @jonrsharpe's suggestion is a much better way to go than relying on hard-coding the global name (`B`) of a *particular* back-end instance in the front-end methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have an instance of Backend inside your Frontend class

```
class Frontend:
    def __init__(self):
        self.backend = Backend()

    def main(self):
        self.backend.one()
```

If you need to configure more stuff in the backend before passing it to Frontend, add a second argument on `__init__` and supply it. Otherwise, you may configure the Backend inside the initialization of Frontend